# Syntax to specify Namespace when using helper.RouteUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am using Asp.Net MVC 2 - RC w/ Areas.

I am receiving an ambigious controller name exception due to having same controller name in two different areas.

I've read Phil Haack's post [Ambiguous Controller Names With Areas](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx)

I can't figure out the syntax when trying to use UrlHelper (I have an extensions class).

e.g.

```
public static string MyAreaHome(this UrlHelper helper) {
    return helper.RouteUrl("ARoute", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```

I've tried the obvious of adding namespace="mynamespace" but that didn't work, it just added the namespace to the url. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can work around it by using two separate routes. I think this is also what Phil is trying to demonstrate in the route registration example on the '[Ambiguous Controller Names With Areas](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx)' post

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ARoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "BRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Then you can refer to both routes like this:

```
public static string MyAreaHome(this UrlHelper helper) {
    return helper.RouteUrl("ARoute", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}

public static string MyOtherAreaHome(this UrlHelper helper) {
    return helper.RouteUrl("BRoute", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```

Comment: This helped resolve the issue. On the "general" route I specified the namespace. In the area route, where the routes are registered I specified the area namespace and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
helper.RouteUrl("ARoute", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Area = "YourArea" });
```

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either. It added the area to the url as a querystring